# How to returning a gameobject to its original position when release a grab from touch controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm having a scene with multiple gameobjects that i can grab. I am using the Grabber and Grabbable scripts from **VRIF PACKAGE**, but I want to set it up so that when the player releases the object in a certain distance, it snaps back to it's original position and rotation.

Comment: What have you tried? Please see: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://wiki.beardedninjagames.com/en/Core/Grabber) there are `Grabber Events` on which you could subscribe a script, which then remembers the previous position(-s) (and rotation(-s)) when you start grabbing and then restores the GameObject when you let go.

You can then define the thresholds (e.g. your prefered distance), in which the GameObject snaps back to original position.